# Update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher / generate Flutter signed APK

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I'm developing a flutter cross-platform supporting app using Android Studio.

Now I'm trying to generate signed APK for app-release but I face this following error:

```
'Generating signed Bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher'.
```

How can I fix this? I have not a single clue..

Best regards!

Answer (score 23):

I got this error when trying to build "Generate Signed Bundle / APK" from the Flutter workspace.

The solution for me was to open the Android project folder in Android studio (as Android project) and the error is gone.

Steps: In Android Studio,

1. Go to file -> Open project,
2. Navigate to the flutter project, and go to the android subfolder.
3. You can click open and it will open the project as if it is an Android project
4. Wait until gradle download finishes (per @Bourne)
5. Click menu Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK
   It should build without complaining about the Gradle plugin.

Comment: Can you please you share what you mean by opening Android project as android project in android studio?

Comment: In android studio, go to file, open project, navigate to the flutter project, and go to the android subfolder. You can click open and it will open the project as if it is an android project.

Comment: Dude, you actually solved my 2 day journey with this problem. Sorry stackoverflow but normal "+1" won't express my feeling of hapiness. Bless u

Comment: I would just add to @Harmen and say that when I did this, Android Studio spent about 15-20 minutes downloading gradle related packages in the background.  I didn't see the "Generate Signed Bundle or APK" option until those updates were finished.  But it did work for me!

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your Android Gradle Plugin.

These posts should help:
[How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: Thanks, I look into it! I wonder maybe you know how to delete keystore that I forgotten/can't find?

Answer (score 3):

Update your Android studio editor with 3.4.2 or gradle version 5.1.1 you need to update your editor. Or else only change gradle version with 
 Click here 5.1.1 https://gradle.org/releases/

Answer (score 3):

you can update the build.gradle file
[image]