# ERROR: Could not find method platform() for arguments - React Native - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, gradle, react-native-firebase

Has anyone faced this issue following the official documentation for `react-native-firebase`?

```
ERROR: Could not find method platform() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:21.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Open File
```

This happens after editing the two `build.gradle` files and clicking `sync` on the Android Studio popup. I think it is there because of a gradle issue.

Any help is welcome. Could not find a similar issue though.

**Edited question with the two `build.gradle` files as per the request by Gabriele Mariotti.**

This is the `build.gradle` file contents.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `app/build.gradle` file contents.

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 33
        versionName "2.2.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

both `build.gradle` files are modified according to the documentation.

Comment: post the build.gradle files

Comment: Running in to a similar issue on Gradle 5.5.1

Comment: Manage to figure it?

I'm getting the same issue with the aws-sdk. This link here says you need to add "enableFeaturePreview('IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT')" to your settings.gradle

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html

Comment: Does that line resolve it?

Answer (score 13):

So, I think you're using Gradle 4.x. I had the same issue. Upgrading to 5.0 solved it: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html

Comment: Correct! I updated and came here to update the question and saw this answer. I resolved by going into gradle 5.1.1

Comment: @buddhiv How have you upgraded the gradle to 5.0?

Comment: I can't get it working with react-native-firebase v6

Comment: Kevin I followed the docs to update the gradle version. There are plenty examples to do so. You just change the necessary places and Android Studio will take care of the rest. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio

Answer (score 8):

Solution: put in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Follow this link:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3287