# How to fix sudden and generic Gradle Project Sync Failed error

Tags: android, gradle

I've been developing an Android app for a few months. When I left work last night, everything was fine, but when I returned this morning I had to restart my computer and therefore Android Studio. Now when I attempt to build the project I get the error "Failed to resolve: com.android.support", along with "Grade project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly."

I've tried updating to the latest Android Studio version, updating Gradle to the latest version (I used the table in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio/37267191) thread to properly sync the plugin/gradle versions), rolling back to a working version via Git, and switching the `google()` repository to

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
```

[Here's a screenshot of the Build view showing the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRKZP.jpg)

[And here's a screenshot of the app build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzzpV.jpg)

"Failed to resolve: com.android.support" has proven to be too generic to find a solution via Google.

Comment: could you show the app gradle depdencies snapshot?

Comment: @AshokKumar I added another screenshot to the post

Comment: @AshokKumar I solved the problem, see my answer if you're interested. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem in a pretty simple way. I created a new project, opened the app-level build.gradle file, added all the extra dependencies from the old project, then replaced the old file with the newly created one. This solved the issue. Upon inspecting the differences between old and new I realized that somehow

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion '29.x.x'
}
```

had been added to the old project and it was one version greater than the `compileSdkVersion`. After Gradle finally synced successfully it notified me to fix the buildToolsVersion, which is now the same as the compileSdkVersion.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using **invalidate cache/restart** option from android studio

Comment: also cross check gradle offline work is unchecked and there is no problem from android studio proxy.

Comment: I've confirmed gradle offline is unchecked, what do you mean by android studio proxy?

Comment: is there any proxy required in your connected internet?

Comment: Not sure but I doubt anything changed between yesterday and today

Answer (score 0):

When i encounter that kind of error I always do the same routine:

File > Invalidate caches/Restart
Build > Clear Project
Build > Rebuild Project
File > Sync project with Gradle files

I hope that it will help you too. Good luck!

Comment: I solved the problem, see my answer if you're interested. Thanks for your help.