# How to upgrade gradle from 4.4.1 to latest on Fedora?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am running Fedora 31 and Gradle 4.4.1 is installed on the machine. I have my Android project under Android Studio 3.5.2. When I run the command "gradle wrapper" in order to generate "gradlew" wrapper script, I get the following error:

Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/danesh/open/code/zink/zink_android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

I also have "gradle-5.4.1-all.zip" in the file "gradle-wrapper.properties"- Here comes the tree structure of my gradle directory under my project root directory:

├── gradle

│   └── wrapper

│       ├── build

│       │   ├── libs

│       │   │   └── wrapper.jar

│       │   └── tmp

│       │       └── jar

│       │           └── MANIFEST.MF

│       ├── build.gradle

│       ├── gradle

│       │   └── wrapper

│       │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar

│       │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties

│       ├── gradlew

│       ├── gradlew.bat

│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar

│       ├── gradle-wrapper.properties

│       └── settings.gradle

I have tried to execute the command "gradle wrapper" under project directory and got the aforementioned error. I also executed same command under "gradle/wrapper" and the file "gradlew" was actually generated but the script does nothing when I run for instance "./gradlew build" and just shows the message that "1 file is up-to-date" and nothing is generated.

Does anybody know how can I generate valid gradle wrapper file so I will be able to build and run my unit tests and download all dependencies using command line and gradle wrapper script?

I also would like to know how can I upgrade my gradle to latest (it should be version 6 up to November 2019)? It seems the official repos are not updated to the latest version of gradle.

Thanks in advance,

D.

Comment: Tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272475/5192105?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Yes I have tried that. In Android Studio the plugin version is set to 3.5.2 and the Greadle version to 5.4.1 but when I run "gradle --version" in command line I get the 4.4.1 for gradle version. This is weird too since apparently Android Studio is using newer version of gradle that I cannot execute using command line.

Comment: Try invalidating your cache and try again. Also if the problem persists use a local gradle dist by downloading from the official website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to [upgrade gradle per project using the gradle wrapper](https://gradle.org/install/). Assuming you've previously initiated your project with `gradle init`, make sure that you are using java 8. As you'll get an exception with java 11 and higher.

```sh
update-alternatives --config java
```

Then update gradle locally using the wrapper:

```sh
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.2.2 --distribution-type=bin
```

And verify that your project now uses 6.2.2:

```sh
$ ./gradlew           

> Task :help

Welcome to Gradle 6.2.2.

To run a build, run gradlew <task> ...
...
```

Comment: in IntelIJ IDEA 2019.3.3 it doesn't help, although when `./gradlew` is run it shows brand new version installed, but when `gradle --version` is run it shows still the **old (4.4.1) version**

Comment: Just restarted my IDE and it works. BTW, I've also upgraded ti via SDKMan (not sure that also had positive impact on it to work). Thanks for this suggestion though. :)