# Stripe plugin in not working. error found in app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

My flutter application is running perfectly but When I am applying `stripe_payment` plugin I am getting this error. `Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.`
 without adding this plugin into yaml file everything's perfect. 
any solution for this problem ? I did found some solution but they are not working as they are showing some other errors.

```
error processing C:\Users\Waqas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.61\df4b474e71be02c1349c3292d98886f888d1f7\bcprov-jdk15on-1.61.jar
        java.lang.RuntimeException
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
            at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
            at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
            at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
        java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
            at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getInitalGraphData(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:162)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.makeDesugaringGraph(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:130)
            at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:160)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getDependenciesPaths(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:231)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.getD8DesugaringCacheInfo(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:461)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:375)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
            at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
            at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
            at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
        > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

        BUILD FAILED in 36s
        Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/1447, Stripe SDK requires Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.1 or higher. I facing the same issue as you and solved it by upgrading gradle into 3.5.0. Can take a look on [How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio) to upgrade your gradle.

Comment: but the same plug in working when I download a stripe project from github