# Flutter Can't build apk, gradle build version Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 5.6.2

Tags: flutter, apk

I had to generate a new key for the application, so I contacted google and followed the step by step to update the key, when I put the new key and went to generate the apk, then the following problem appeared.
[thas the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk563.png)

I looked in the gradle and the version to use is the correct one, still I get the following error.

[Flutter Doctor result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Hdf.png)

How can I force the use of the correct gradle?
Is there any other configuration I need to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)

Comment: try restarting the Android Studio ?

Comment: in your android studio select `File>Invalidate Catches/ restart` and see if that helps