# How to upgrade gradle in android studio 4.1

Tags: android-studio

android studio 4.1 doesn't have gradle settings as in previous versions. Currently I am retricted on 5.6.2. How to upgrade?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70823558/8583692).

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to upgrade:
**Method 1:-**
Click on File in Android Studio -> Project Structure -> Click on Project(on left panel) ->Change the Gradle version from selecting it from the drop down menu.

**Method 2:-**
Open the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in your project, find this URL - `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip` and replace `6.5` with your desired version. Sync the project after changing.
For information regarding Android gradle, refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#:%7E:text=Update%20Gradle%20%20%20%20Plugin%20version%20,2.10%20-%202.13%20%2011%20more%20rows%20)