# Android gradle plugin update to version 7.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-7.0

I want to update to android gradle plugin 7.0. Is there any way I could test what changes I will be required to do in my project or code? Is there any preview tool in android studio?

Comment: Why you don't just create a backup, or use version control?

Comment: Is there any preview tool available ? thats my question read carefully before you answer is there anything mentioned related to version control?

Comment: Version control is your 'preview' tool. Not sure what else you need.

Comment: No I heard android studio has feature where you can preview changes before upgrading looking for it

Comment: The preview is rather pointless, without undo functionality (version control is being assumed). I mean, how would you determine if it breaks the build, by looking at the preview, without applying it? This migration merely depends on plugins/scripts being compatible with Gradle 7.2 ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If 'preview tool' you saying is about the **[AGP Upgrade Assistant](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/05/android-studio-42.html)**:

> The assistant allows you to toggle the commands that will be executed
> on your project to upgrade to a higher version of AGP, *preview exactly
> which files will be affected by the AGP upgrade*, and lastly globally
> update deprecated configurations.

The assistant is automatically prompted when you open a project which is using an older gradle version (or select it manually from `Tools > AGP Upgrade Assistant...`).

[image: prompt]

[image: pop up]

[image: preview 0]

[image: preview 1]

[image: preview 2]

When you select **Show Usages** button:

[image: preview 3]

And for *actual preview* purpose, I would back up the project folder (e.g. simply compress to a zip or ideally using a VCS as @MartinZeitler suggests) and then execute update with AGP Upgrade Assistant by submitting **Run selected steps** button.

If I encounter a problem by upgrade, just delete the project folder and extract from the zip or rollback with VCS.