# The specified Gradle installation directory does not exist error after Android Studio update 2021 1 1 patch2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

After updating Android studio, my project now throws error `The specified Gradle installation directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.14.1' does not exist.`
When checking that installation path, there is no gradle folder.

I also tested a sample project, and that seems to be working.

Update: found the solution in this comment: [How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio?rq=1)

Answer (score 90):

I have solved like this:

You'll:

In **Android Studio** -> **File** -> **Settings** -> **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Build Tools** -> **Gradle**

In "**Use Gradle from**" you choose **'gradle-wrapper.properties' file**. And in **Gradle JDK** you choose what you need.

Comment: On a mac, it's Android Studio -> Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle ...

Answer (score 3):

Update your Gradle JDK from File->Project Structure->SDK Location click JDK was moved to Gradle Settings and update [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXwgh.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, try running Android Studio as an administrator. Doing so may allow Android Studio to download the required Gradle files automatically.