# Android Studio Build Immediate Fail - Is there an Android version issue that makes older code unable to build?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This example code was taken straight from github.  I am confident that this code is supposed to build but I suspect something in the compiler of Android Studio has changed, updated, or with a newer version of the Android operating system something needs to be updated in the source code of an app.  This is because a build and/or gradle sync has this error immediately.  Nothing major has changed in the code.  I suspect this might be a common thing and I suspect someone must know something about this and how to fix it.  Please advise.
http://millionthompson.com/images/work/015.png

Is there an Android version issue that makes older code unable to build?

I carefully looked into all this and I found that it must have something to do with Gradle version.  Do you have any views or knowledge on how to updatge the grande and gradle plugin version?

[image: http://www.millionthompson/images/work/Gradles.png]

Comment: 1) Linking to images is [discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/295004) 2) You should state what your current Android Studio version & SDK version are (if you suspect it is a version issue). 3) It would help others by linking to the github repo you are using to see if they have similar problems. 4) Your project does not appear to be identified as Android project in Android Studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)